# arduino interrupt variable not working

Tags: arduino

I am a beginner with arduino and I'm trying to make a sinus wave generator. Since I've recently found I can't put everything into main void loop, I'm trying to use interrupts. I have problem with changing variable inside of the interrupt (Delay), I don't know where's the mistake.
Here is my code:

```
int sine256[]  = { //256 sin values from 0 to 2pi
};

int i = 0;
int sensorPin = 7;  
int outputPin = 6;
volatile float Delay = 10000;


void setup()
{  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(outputPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT); 
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(sensorPin), freq, RISING);

}
void loop()
{
  analogWrite(6,sine256[i]);
  i = i + 1;
  if(i == 256){
    i = 0; 
    } 

  Serial.println(Delay);

  delayMicroseconds(Delay);
}

void freq() {
  Delay = Delay/2;     
}
```

Comment: On your `void setup` ,change `pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT); ` to `pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT_PULLUP);`. Mean `INPUT` not include `RISING /  FALLING` edge. @nyuhanC

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Try this:

```
int sine256[]  = { //256 sin values from 0 to 2pi
};

int i = 0;
int sensorPin = 7;  
int outputPin = 6;
volatile float Delay = 10000;


void setup()
{  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(outputPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT); 
  //attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(sensorPin), freq, RISING);

}
void loop()
{
  analogWrite(6,sine256[i]);
  i = i + 1;
  if(i == 256){
    i = 0; 
  } 

  Serial.println(Delay);

  freq();
  delay(Delay);
}

void freq() {
  Delay = Delay / 2;     
}
```

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt

Try taking a look at that.

What model are you using?

Comment: i figured out i was using wrong pin, on uno i should be doing on pin 2 or 3. But still it's not working properly, i see on the serial monitor that delay changes when i press the button, but the output frequency does not change :/

Comment: o it seem that it is working with regular delay(), whats wrong then with delayMicroseconds??

Comment: @nyuhanC good question, it may just be a glitch in the hardware, could be dependent on the board. i know delay() works on all boards. it might be worth putting a delay in the loop, and executing you code through the loop. I've edited my answer to show how i'd have done it

Comment: still doesn't do i might just stick with delay() to avoid further trouble. thanks for help :) i have also posted my final code

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that causes me troubles now is the button; when i press it, it often respond as if i had pressed the button multiple times (2,3 or 4x).

This is my final code for now. Since the execution time for a void loop is 12 microseconds, i've calculated delay required to run a generator on 20,40 & 60Hz.

```
int sine256[]  = { //256 sin values from 0 to 2pi (from 0 to 255)
int i = 0;
int sensorPin = 2;  
volatile int outputPin = 7;
volatile float Delay = 1000;
int time1;
int time2;

void setup()
{  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(outputPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT_PULLUP); 
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(sensorPin), freq, FALLING);

}
void loop()
{  
  //time1 = micros();

  analogWrite(outputPin,sine256[i]);
  i = i + 1;
  if(i == 256){
    i = 0; 
    } 

  //time2 = micros();

  //Serial.println(time2 - time1);

  delay(Delay);
}

void freq() {  
  outputPin = 6;
  if(Delay == 0.02){
    analogWrite(6,LOW);
    outputPin = 7;
    Delay = 1000;
  }
  if(Delay == 0.04){
    Delay = 0.02;
  }
  if(Delay == 0.09){
    Delay = 0.04;
  }
  if((Delay == 1000)&&(outputPin == 6)){
    Delay = 0.09;
  } 
  Serial.println(Delay);  
}
```